# How do I execute a code in js that when clicked on "open" text not only opens the bar but also changes the text to "close" to close it again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, dom-events

How do I execute a code in js that when clicked on "open" text not only opens the bar but also changes the text to "close" to close it again?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="close">
        Close</div>

    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function () {
            document.querySelector('.main').hidden = true;
            document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = open;
        }


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can done with multiple ways, you can use following simple script and modify style display properties -

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="box" style="display: none;">
    <div id="close">Close</div>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="open" >Open</div>
</div>
```

and script as:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", openFunc);
document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", closeFunc);


function openFunc() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = 'none';
}

function closeFunc() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("open").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the" open" text where close is i.e on the top right corner and change it to" close" keeping it at same spot by using the innerHTML property.I don't want the text on left and right wanna keep both at spot.